# JqueryUI theme with SASS

Tags: jquery-ui, sass

Has anyone used the jQueryUI theme in Sass? A search gave a few projects at Github, but did anyone use them? Is it possible to change the colors easily if only the base theme is available (if theme roller is not possible to use with).
Or what do you suggest to theme the base theme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take a jQuery UI theme you like and use `$ sass-convert` to make it Sass or Scss

Article on sass-convert utility: [article](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/#_2)

Comment: broken article link

Answer (score 1):

Your best baseline is to do a `$ sass-convert` on the jQuery UI Twitter Bootstrap theme – It uses LESS, so `sass-convert` will translate the variables, nesting, etc. [You can find the LESS versions here at addyosmani/jquery-ui-bootstrap](http://www.github.com/addyosmani/jquery-ui-bootstrap/tree/master/css/less)

Answer (score 1):

[This project](https://github.com/jhilden/jquery-ui-sass-rails) has SASS converted jQuery-UI files with the various styling/theming options set by SASS variables. The files are under app/assets/stylesheets.  The project also has partials which define the variables in a way that match the default schemes in the themeroller. I simply copied the entire stylesheet folder into my project and I am importing the files I want to use into my main SASS sheet.